# Timeout a input(prompt) after 60 seconds of inactivity from user[python]

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, timeout, user-input

```
activity = input("Enter the message:")
```

if no input from user it should be auto-stopped , giving a message no activity from the user. i am a newbie to python. any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it like this with threads:

```py
import threading
import queue

result_queue = queue.Queue()
def input_target(queue):
  queue.put(input('Enter the message:'))
threading.Thread(target=input_target, daemon=True, args=(result_queue,)).start()
result = None
try:
  result = result_queue.get(timeout=1)
except queue.Empty:
  result = None
print([result])
```

Please note that the thread continues running after the timeout has been reached, so subsequent reads from stdin won't work.

Alternatively, if you want to make subsequent reads work, then you can try calling `select.select` (with a timeout) and `os.read(0, ...)` in a loop, but that doesn't work on Windows (because `select.select` on Windows requires that the filehandle is a socket, which it isn't for console input).

Comment: the code is working as exected, but after continuous looping it is going to random behavior, for ex: queue.put(input('Enter the message:')), it is showing random behavior, sometimes it  works as expected but sometimes takes NONE as output even if we are providing data in the prompt.

Comment: @Togad: The behavior you describe is not a surprise, it matches this from the answer: *subsequent reads from stdin won't work.*. FYI an `input(...)` call is also a read from stdin.